# Complex number pairs - simplficiation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to write an algorithm but I am having a problem solving this equation.  I've never taken linear algebra before and I've tried to solve it, but to no avail.  My goal is to remove `w` from the equation and solve for both `S1 and S2`

The value `w` is set to a value that I am unaware of and it changes several times in a loop.  In order to solve this problem, we must make `F1 = F2` and solve for both `S1 and S2`.

Also `w` will never be equal to 0.

Can someone help me solve this? I would appreciate a hint on how to solve this, I am not asking for spoon feeding.  Here is what I know so far:

- Distributive law is in place
- Associative law is in place
- Multiply complex number pairs: (a, b) * (c, d) = (ac + ad, bc - bd)
- The values w, S1, S2, M1, M2 are complex numbers.  So S1 = (S1a, S1b), S2 = (S2a, S2b), w = (wa, wb), M1 = (M1a, M1b), M2 = (M2a, M2b)

  F1 = w^2 + w * S1 + S2

  F2 = (W + M1) * (W + M2)

  F1 = F2

I've expanded F2 into the following:

```
F2 = (w^2) + (w * M1) + (w * M2) + (M1 * M2)
```

I subtracted w^2 from both sides and now I'm stuck.  I need to remove w from the entire equation so that I can solve for S1 and S2.  But I don't know what to do next.

Here is what I have:

```
w * S1 + S2 = w * M2 + w * M1 + M1 * M2
```

And all the values are complex numbers.  How do I remove w from the equation?

EDIT: I need to make two equations so that I can solve for S1 and S2.  So I'm thinking it has something to do with that; but I'm not entirely sure how to continue.

Comment: When you write "w * S1 + S2 = w * M2 + w * M1 + M1 * M2", are you saying that you want both sides to be equal for all possible values of $w$, or that you want both sides to be equal for some specific value of $w$?

Comment: For all possible values of w

Comment: I think he is wording it poorly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to express $S_1$ and $S_2$ in terms of $M_1$ and $M_2$ such that $$wS_1+S_2=wM_2+wM_1+M_1M_2$$ for all $w$. In order to solve for two unknowns, we usually need two equations, which we can get by setting $w$ to two well-chosen test values. For example, setting $w=0$ immediately gives us $$S_2=M_1M_2.$$

However, there's a wrinkle: you specified that $w$ is never $0$. This won't actually change the final answer, but to be cautious, try setting $w=1$ and $w=-1$. You'll get a pair of equations without $w$, and after simplifying, you should eventually get $S_2=M_1M_2$ after all, plus a similarly simple expression for $S_1$.

Comment: Will this work even if w is always a complex number?

Comment: Short answer, yes. Is there a particular step that you're concerned about?

Comment: Nope, I understand how you came to the solution.  However, I was just worried it would not be the same for all values of w if w = (3, 20001) to w = (20001, 6667) where each step increments/decrements by (+3, -2).

Comment: Okay, there shouldn't be any problems there! Formally, both the real numbers and the complex numbers form a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)), which essentially means that they obey all the same laws for addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. Any algorithm for those operations that you've learned to use on real numbers will also work on complex numbers. It's only with more sophisticated operations, like ordering, roots, and logarithms, that the complex numbers start behaving differently.

Answer (score 1):

Re arrange and get $w$ to left

$$
w (S_1 - M_2 - M_1) = M_1 M_2 - S_2$$

So $$
w = \frac{M_1 M_2 - S_2}{S_1 - M_2 - M_1}$$

Depending on how you represent the complex number you can reduce it to
$$
w =\frac{A + i B}{C + i D} = \frac{(A + i B)(C + i D)}{C^2+D^2} = \frac{AC-BD}{C^2+D^2} + i \frac{AD  + BC}{C^2+D^2}$$

I hope you have functions/subroutines to multiply complex numbers. If not leave a comment

Comment: Yes, I have functions to multiply and add complex numbers.  However, no matter how much I try to remove w from the equation, I fail.  For example, when substituting w into S2 = M1M2 - w(S1 - M2 - M1) I always get S2 = S2.  I have to remove w so that I can solve for both S1 and S2 but my attempts fail.

Comment: You have to combine all of $w$ to one side and then remove $w$ as I show.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help.  That makes it more clear now.